# Appending data in snowflake table

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbi

I am trying to write back data frame R into snowflake table using below code :

```
table_id <- Id(database="database", schema="schema", table="tablename")
dbWriteTable(conn, table_id, R data frame name,append=TRUE,overwrite=FALSE)
```

It works for the first time when table is not there, but fails to append data. It throws an error as "Object already exists". I tried using dbAppendTable as well, but it alsi does not work.

Comment: I am running into similar problems. I _think_ my issue may be due to using JDBC to connect to snowflake, instead of ODBC. I am working on a workaround that first writes to a temporary table, then `INSERT ... SELECT`s to append to the existing table.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
table_id <- Id(database="database", schema="schema", table="tablename")
dbWriteTable(conn, table_id, R data frame name, append=TRUE)
```

Comment: for value=table, I should replace it with table name right ?

Comment: If I add it, it throws an error " Unable to find an inherited method for dbWritetable" for signature "snowflake","sql","function"

Comment: can you try this:  dbWriteTable(conn, table_id, R data frame name, append=TRUE)

Comment: also, what is the version of DBI you are using?

Comment: >packageVerision("DBI")

Comment: I tried the above syntax, it throws an error saying "Object already exist". Package version for DBI is 1.1.0